# Can someone explain these programming terms: reference semantics, non-linear mutable state?

Tags: c++, reference, functional-programming, state, mutable

Can you explain these terms for me: reference semantics and value semantics (and how they contrast) and non-linear mutable state. They are mentioned in the comments to the book review in this link
http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2849

The book is of course "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++" Many commentators are calling the book useless for teaching for ignoring reference semantics, I can almost guess what this means, but I am not 100% sure.

I think they mean programming using references types (e.g. classes) is the way to go versus programming using values types (e.g. struct)

I doubt my understanding, because I doubt bjarne stroustup would do that, C++ is about classes ... so I think there is something deeper about the term reference semantics, something less than obvious at least to me

Also the terms linear and non-linear states were used, which seem intriguing, and which I dont understand.

So if someone can explain those terms, that would be great

Comment: In C++, classes and structs are basically the same. Their difference certainly has no relation to reference vs. value semantics.

Comment: You do notice that "the book is worthless" was written 6 months *before* the book was published? How did they know?

Answer (score 2):

Don't read too much into those comments. They're not that enlightning.

Basically, "reference semantics" means that you're using `int*` whereas value semantics mean that you're using `int`. "Achilleas Margaritis" is complaining that the book uses `vector<int>` and he thinks that in reality you usually have `vector<int*>`. (I obviously disagree).

"non-lineair mutable state" seems to be what I call non-orthogonal state. E.g. you can set `Foo.x` to 7 and `Foo.y` to 8 unless `Foo.z` is 9. In particular, it seems to mean that the set of allowed mutations depends non-trivially on previous operations. That's true if you're managing `char[]` yourself, but the mutators of `std::string` behave far mroe reasonable.